# Missing `breakInside` rule on GrooCSS

Tags: css, groovy, dsl

I am using GrooCSS 1.0-GA to write CSS. Unfortunately, it seems like GrooCSS doesn't support breakInside so the following code:

```
GrooCSS.process(new Config(prettyPrint: true)) {
  body {
    breakInside 'avoid'
  }
}.tap {
  println it
}
```

produces the following error:

```
No signature of method: org.groocss.StyleGroup.breakInside() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [avoid]
```

Is there a way to escape or to write rules that are not implemented by GrooCSS? I must have missed this on the documentation.

I am aware that pageBreakInside exists but I would rather be able to use both if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried replacing

```
breakInside 'avoid'
```

With

```
raw 'break-inside: avoid;'
```

Or

```
add style('break-inside', 'avoid')
```

Comment: It seems that this adds the string outside the selector.

```
break-inside: avoid;
body {
    line-height: 4pt;
}
```

Comment: Had another guess... Never used groocss 

Comment: `add style(...)` worked!